# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous for conditional if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue using a dataframe to store inventory data and creating a conditional if statement based on whether the column contains the string ("abc") & the status is "available". There could be multiple rows for the same type of item so I believe that is part of the problem but not sure how to handle that. I only want to send an email notification if the name of the item equals contained string and status are available.

```
mergedf = pd.merge(df, df2)
         
item1 = mergedf[mergedf['name'].str.lower().str.contains("item1") & mergedf['status'].str.lower().str.contains("available")]
        
item2 = mergedf[mergedf['name'].str.lower().str.contains("item2") & mergedf['status'].str.lower().str.contains("available")]
        
item3 = mergedf[mergedf['name'].str.lower().str.contains("item3") & mergedf['status'].str.lower().str.contains("available")]
        
item4 = mergedf[mergedf['name'].str.lower().str.contains("item4") & mergedf['status'].str.lower().str.contains("available")]
        
print(item1)
print(item2) 
with open ("recipientlist.txt", "r+") as f:
      email_list = [line.strip() for line in f]
        for email in email_list:
            if email == "abc@gmail.com" and item1 or item2:
                        send_email()
                        print("email sent!")
            elif email == "xyz@gmail.com" and item3 or item4:
                        send_email()
                        print("email sent!")
            else:
                        print("no emails sent, nothing in stock")

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [sku, name, price, manufacturer, status, url, status check]
Index: []
       sku  ... status check
0  134463  ...         True
```

> Traceback (most recent call last)
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Not a solution per se, but you can simplify your code by first getting all the available items with `available_df = mergedf[mergedf.status == 'available']` and then searching for the item names in the new dataframe. Also, instead of `str.lower().str.contains` you can just `str.contains('item1', case=False)`.

Comment: Ok thanks I will simply the code based on your suggestions.